# xray document generator generate nested tests steps

Tags: jira, jira-xray

trying to generate a document using document generator where test steps are added as called teststeps in manual steps

we want to fetch details like test steps of attached nested tests

we need to generate a document with xray document  which is having  multiple called tests in its steps . but when I am trying to do it , I am not able to print the test steps of called test case from the parent

I am attaching the the the screenshot for reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSp9y.jpg)

In above we are able to get information for steps 1 to 3 but how to get the information for step 4 ?

In document generator I am able to detect that 4th step is called test but I am not able to fetch its details like description and test steps for 4th

Also we have multiple such test cases which are called inside test steps of other test case. and we want to fetch all those steps details in one document like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXPHw.jpg)

Below is example of multiple nested test steps we want to print out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBo8h.jpg)

I am referring below link : https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Exporting+a+Test#ExportingaTest-ModularTestSteps

Comment: Are you using Xray on Jira server/datacenter or Xray on Jira cloud?

Comment: have you tried my suggestion as provided on my answer? if so and it was helpful, can you please mark it as correct? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xray on Jira server/datacenter, you can use [this template](https://store.getxporter.app/view/143?platf=XRAY&cats=1&sort=1&order=desc) that is available for free. you can install it from your Xray administration settings; you can also download and customize it.
We've written an extensive [documentation page](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Document+Generator+Template%3A+Test+Report) explaining it. The template only shows 2 levels, out-of-the-box.

If you're using Xray on Jira  cloud, then use [this template](https://store.getxporter.app/view/145?platf=XRAYCLOUD&cats=1&sort=1&order=desc) instead.
The [documentation page explaining it](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Document+Generator+Template%3A+Test+Report) is also available.
And the proper Document Generator documentation page is [this one](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Exporting+Test), by the way.